# Simplifying long conditional if sentence

Tags: java

I have a conditional if statement like this

```
if ((a && (b || c)) ||
     (b && (a || c))) {
}
```

basically what I'm trying to achieve is that I can only have one option true, but two is not ok!

Can it be more simplified, looks redundant to me!
Or should I extract it to a function?

*edit*

```
if (a && !b && !c) // process a
if (b && !a && !c) // process b
if (c && !a && !b) // process c
if (!a && !b && c!) // none present exception
else {} // more than one case exception
```

Comment: Write a truth table!

Comment: The part saying you can't have any two options true is very unclear. If `c`is true, both `(a && b || c)` and `(b && a || c)` will be evaluated to true.

Comment: As said in a comment below: "your requirement doesn't match the expression you posted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment and the edit, each line is the development of the previous one:

```
(a && (b || c)) || (b && (a || c))
((a && b) || (a && c)) || ((a && b) || (b && c))
(a && b) || (a && c) || (a && b) || (b && c)
```

You have a duplicate, so you can turn it to: (those lines are equals)

```
(a && b) || (a && c) || (b && c)
(a && (b ||c)) || (b&&c)
```

Comment: sorry if the code was unclear, it should read like this `if ((a && (b || c)) || (b && (a || c)))` no two's true are allowed.

Comment: this is look like the fewest letters `(a && (b ||c)) || (b&&c)` and is explanatory as well, thank you!

Comment: I think it's better to leave it at this state: `(a && b) || (a && c) || (b && c)` and not `(a && (b ||c)) || (b&&c)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can be simpler, this would be more than enough since `a && b` will give the same result as `b && a`:

```
if (a && b || c) {

}
```

---

**Note:** the original question was *completely* different, and asked to simplify the following expression:

```
if ((a && b || c) ||
     (b && a || c)) {
}
```

Comment: Actually `a && b` not exactly the same as `b && a` because the operators are short circuit operations - if `a` and `b` are methods only one could be executed. If this would matter it would probably be a code smell though :)

Comment: your case does not handle a being false

Comment: You should explain that this behaviour is due to the && operator being commutative

Answer (score 1):

```
&& operator is Commutative so a && b or b && a results in same output.

Now your condition becomes like this
if ((a && b || c) ||
     (a && b || c)) {
}

|| operator is Idempotent so x || x results x

your expression becomes (a && b) || c

But in java && and || operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior

First operand will be evaluated first and then second operand will be evaluated only if need so you can choose which operand to keep first based on operand complexity.
```

Comment: what about the case where a is false and c and b are true, your case does not handle that!

Comment: @JonB instead of saying the answers don't handle this or that case, could you explain what you want to do? Because right now it's unclear and people are just guessing

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, this is what I'm trying to simplify `if ((a && (b || c)) || (b && (a || c))) {}` no two's true are allowed. Hope this clarifies it, and again sorry for the badly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c || (a && b) {
...
}
```

The 2 large conditions are the same...  ´&&` is commutative

Comment: basically what I'm trying to achieve is that I can not have any two options true, but one is ok!

Comment: @JonB you might want to explain that in your question. Note, however, that your requirement doesn't match the expression you posted (`a && b` would require both to be true).